# Invalid Syntax Turtles

Tags: python

I have been trying to write a code to familiarize myself with turtles, and the code is supposed to make 500 randomly colored boxes.  This is the code:

```
import turtle
from random import randint
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue', 'orange']
window = turtle.Screen()
window.title('500 Boxes')

for x in range(500):
    box = turtle.Turtle()
    box.color(colors[randint(0, 6)]
    for x in range(4):
        box.forward(30)
        box.left(90)
```

Then, when I run the code I get this error:

```
line 10: Invalid Syntax
```

I am really not sure what the problem is.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on this line:

```
box.color(colors[randint(0, 6)]
#                            --^
```

Whenever you get a weird syntax error on a line that looks fine, it is a good idea to check the line above it and count the number of parenthesis/brackets.  Usually, the problem is simply that you forgot one.